Which HTML tags and attributes should be allowed as user-input for an application to reduce risk of cross-site scripting exploits?
In a given scenario where users of an application can create note-content in Quill, what tags and attributes should be whitelisted in a policy file. I am using OWASP AntiSamy for sanitization.
I am not very familiar with JS or HTML and therefore unsure of what tags to whitelist.
I have included a list of some tags and attributes, but not sure if I am missing anything
        <tag name="b" action="validate"/>
        <tag name="i" action="validate"/>
        <tag name="u" action="validate"/>
        <tag name="em" action="validate"/>
        <tag name="mark" action="validate"/>
        <tag name="strong" action="validate"/>

        
        <tag name="p" action="validate"/>
        <tag name="br" action="validate"/>
        <tag name="ul" action="validate"/>
        <tag name="ol" action="validate"/>
        <tag name="li" action="validate"/>

       
        <tag name="a" action="validate">
            <attribute name="href" action="validate">
                <regexp-list>
                    <regexp value="^https?://.*"/>
                    <!-- other safe links -->
                </regexp-list>
            </attribute>
            <attribute name="title" onInvalid="remove"/>
            <attribute name="target" onInvalid="remove"/>
        </tag>


None. Use markdown. If you have to allow HTML, then use a server-side library to sanitise the input. Do not roll your own solution

A good library for nodejs is something like DOMPurify, which only allows actual HTML and strips out any scripts and the like. It's scripts that you need to watch out for, HTML is mostly harmless to save. Like Rory, I would not roll your own, use community knowledge accumulated over time as they will catch more edge cases than you can come up with.

@RoryMcCrossan — Since markdown allows raw HTML to be included in it, just using markdown isn't good advice. Care needs to be taken to use/configure a markdown parser that doesn't allow raw HTML.

@Quentin Very true - perhaps my first comment was a little flippant, but that was implied.

@somethinghere I've only glanced at it, but it looks like Antisamy may be similar to DOMPurify.

@Barmar When I did my research into this two years ago I stumbled on DOMPurify and it had some raving reviews, haven't really looked back. Let's just say DOMPUrify gets my personal stamp of approval.
